# How to modify ng-disabled attribute for a form element externally using Javascript and get it to take effect?

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJS directive with a form and form elements. I don't have the ability to make any changes to this directive's original markup or code. One form element has an ng-disabled="some expression". I want to change this expression just after the page loads. So I used jQuery's ready function to change the expression to a different one. (I can get a reference to the scope and controller and used $apply(). Probably not applicable here.)

When the page loads I see the element having ng-disabled="my new expression". The new expression evaluates to true upon the page load but the element is not disabled due to the original expression evaluating to false I guess.

```
<button.... ng-disabled="some expression" ...></button> <--- original one. I can't change its code

<button.... ng-disabled="a new expression" ...></button> <--- after page loads
```

I know changing the expression is not enough. How do I get AngularJS to evaluate the updated expression and make the button disabled or enabled based on the updated expression's result?

Answer (score 0):

After changing expression you need to somehow re-compile element, however it might be too tricky to do outside of angular.

If you look at source code https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/9bff2ce8fb170d7a33d3ad551922d7e23e9f82fc/src/ng/directive/attrs.js you may see that ngDisabled directive just adds a watcher to set attribute value, so you can just remove that watcher and add your own:

```
_.remove($scope.$$watchers, w => w.exp === 'some expression');

$scope.$watch('a new expression', function newWatchFn(value) {
        // you can use another selector for element ofc. or get elem before outside this watch
        angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-disabled="some expression"]')).attr('disabled', !!value);
});
```

Notice though that is very tricky and unstable - it is hard to find right watcher and right element, if that element is re-created with ng-if this hack is gone, etc.etc. but it works.